# How can I return the last element number from a tuple that satisfies a condition?

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples

How can I return the largest number in a sorted tuple `an` that is still smaller than a given number (ratio)?

Here is my code:

```
def returnPrevious(width, height):
    an = (2,3,4,6,8,9,12)
    z = -1
    for i in an:
        if (width//height) >= i:
         z += 1   
        else: break
    return an[z]
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do and what is not working in your code

Comment: it is working, i am asking for a better way to do this, I don't like the use of z. Thank you anyway

Comment: So, can you explain what is the purpose of this code - find the first entry that is greater than `width // height`?

Comment: Why do you need `z`? You can just return `i` when it's greater then width//height. What should happen when there isn't such an `i`?

Comment: yes but i need to return the previus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reverse the order of the numbers then you can just return the first match:

```
def returnPrevious(width, height):
    an = (12,9,8,6,4,3,2)
    for i in an:
        if width//height >= i:
            return i
    return None
```

You could even do it in a single statement by using `next()`, which returns the first element from an iterable, or a default value of our choice (`None`) if the iterable is empty.

```
def returnPrevious(width, height):
    return next((i for i in (12,9,8,6,4,3,2) if width//height >= i), None)
```

Comment: This is nice, especially the default `None`

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this instead, you wouldn't get rid of the z, but it's cleaner

```py
def returnPrevius(width, height):
    an = (2,3,4,6,8,9,12)
    z = None
    for i in an:
        if (width//height) >= i:
         z = i  
        else: break
    return z
```

Comment: Better to call `z` `prev` or smth

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
import itertools
def findLast(w,h):
   r = w//h
   return list(itertools.takewhile(lambda e: e < r, an))[-1]
```

or

```
def findLast(w,h):
   r = w//h
   return [e for e in an if e < r][-1]
```

But it builds a list that you don't need only to take last elem from it.

What you can do is reverse the list and find the first elem that matches your condition, then you don't need to remember prev elem. But you still need to handle the case that there is no such elem. Or add 0 to the reversed list as last elem.